# Retrieve @JsonProperty value set in an enum

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, jackson

How do you retrieve the value set in a `@JsonProperty` annotation?

I want to be able to test JSON values of a REST endpoint. I wanted to use the existing enum instead of hardcoding a string. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the value set in the `@JsonProperty` annotation.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public enum StatusType {
    @JsonProperty("unknown")
    UNKNOWN,
    @JsonProperty("warning")
    WARNING,
    @JsonProperty("success")
    SUCCESS,
    @JsonProperty("error")
    ERROR,
    @JsonProperty("info")
    INFO
}
```

Ideally I would want to do something like:

```
 mvc.perform(get("/status"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("status").value(StatusType.INFO))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following (don't forget to handle the exceptions):

```
String value = StatusType.class.getField(StatusType.INFO.name()) 
                         .getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value();
```

---

Alternatively, depending on your needs, you could define your enum as follows, using [`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html):

```
public enum StatusType {

    UNKNOWN("unknown"),
    WARNING("warning"),
    SUCCESS("success"),
    ERROR("error"),
    INFO("info");

    private String value;

    StatusType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
String value = StatusType.INFO.getValue();
```

Comment: For the inverse problem (i.e. getting the Enum from the JsonProperty) the following method could be used :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415585/get-enum-constant-from-jsonproperty-value/64415586#64415586